# How can I reduce/ remove YouTube results in Google search?

Tags: youtube, google-search

I've noticed YouTube videos getting a lot of 'love' from Google in recent searches. This is actually quite annoying. One recent search yielded 10 unrelated videos on page one!

Is it possible to reduce or remove YouTube results from my searches using an operator or preferences and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just have the need to exclude YouTube video from Google result and adding the keyword `-youtube` work for me.

Example:

> How can I remove YouTube results in Google search? -youtube

You can use this method for other website you want exclude from google too.

Comment: -1 This just removes any result with the word youtube. So for example, if you're trying to figure out how to do something in the youtube player, but don't want youtube video results, this will break your search.

Answer (score 6):

You can (temporarily) remove the results of any site from the SERPs using the `-site` operator.

For example, to remove youtube.com videos and search for *skateboard stunts*:

> skateboard stunts -site:youtube.com

The `-` (hyphen) prefix removes that site. Conversely, the following will *only* search youtube.com:

> skateboard stunts site:youtube.com

You only seem to be able to *remove* multiple sites (with multiple `-site` operators). You can't have multiple `site` operators for some reason (it just doesn't find *anything*!).

Comment: Strange... I tried the -site operator a couple of times previously and they still showed up. If they work for others, there must be something unusual to my account...

Comment: It shouldn't depend on your account. The search is bookmarkable so should work for anyone. Make sure you don't have a space after the `-site:`. To be sure, you could try logging out to see if it does make a difference?

Comment: "-site:" doesn't work. Just did a google video search using this and the first three pages of search were nothing but YouTube videos.

Comment: @Luke: This should still work and (just checked) it still works for me on Google Video Search (as well as vanilla Google Search, as mentioned in the question). What exactly are you searching for?

Answer (score 0):

This same thing was driving me crazy because I work in photography and video and Google was constantly taking me to long, often misleading YouTube videos to answer a short simple question.

My solution: set the search engine for my primary browser to DuckDuckGo. It seems that Google results artificially loads YouTube-based results at the top of their list and bury others well below them. Their rankings of both seem to be pretty bogus, as well.

The DDG results only rank the best video results (like those from helpx.adobe.com) near the top.

Yes, I was a bit shocked to discover this, but it has been so true.

Answer (score -1):

You can block Youtube results from here http://www.google.com/reviews/t 
Just block Youtube over there reload the browser and you done

Comment: Google has discontinued this service. However, there are browser addons that restore the functionality of blocking certain website domains in Google. [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/), [GreaseMonkey script](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9275).